# Cannot compile cpp file with c++ 17 in cmd

Tags: c++, cmd, c++17

I use following command `g++ -std=c++17 main.cpp -o main` to compile the cpp file. I get this message `main.cpp:94:15: error: expected unqualified-id before '[' token for (auto [l, r] : a) {` Most probably cmd doesn't compile in c++17, but there no error message about `-std=c++17` flag. If I compile this in the CLion, that will be ok.

Comment: Can you give more context to the code? What is `a`?

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that I have two versions for mingw. The client had a newer version than the one specified in the Path